# switch case not working on menu item - why?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to perform action when click on item in menu and I used switch case to loop over item id

I tried to remove break and tried to play with the code does not work and every time I click on any item in the menu it performs last method in the menu i.e. log out

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_all_users:
            // complete later

        case R.id.menu_account_setting:
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingIntent);
            finish();

        case R.id.menu_log_out:
            auth.signOut();

            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class);
            loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            finish();

            default:
                break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

Comment: *I tried to remove break* why?

Comment: you just forget to use "break;" at the end each statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why you've removed break statement, try in this way :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_all_users:

        return true;
    case R.id.menu_account_setting:
        Intent settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingIntent);
        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_log_out:
        auth.signOut();

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Also cross check all id's are present in xml or not and you're properly inflating menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing break statements in all cases except default.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys I solved it using if statment instead of switch and it worked

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_all_users){

        sendToAllUsers();

    }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_account_setting){

        GoToSetting();

    }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_log_out){

        Logout();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: But this is not the answer to your question!!! just add a break to the very first case and that's all.

Comment: Well, if you had added a `break` statement at the end of each `case`, it would have worked too. There is effectively no difference.